# Mathematics in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to build an application with math functions. What's stumping me is squaring a value. I want to get the value of `(weight x 703) / (height) ^ 2`. The coding of `(height) ^ 2` is what is troubling me. I can't figure out how to code squaring the value of the height. What I have is below:

```
float floatPersonBMI = [personWeight.text floatValue] * 703 / [personHeight.text floatValue];
NSString *stringPersonBMI = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%f", floatPersonBMI];
personBMI.text = stringPersonBMI;
```

What or how do I need to express this equation (code) so that the `[personHeight.text floatValue]` is squared before dividing the weight times 703 or `[personWeight.text floatValue] * 703`??

Answer (score 2):

Did you know that x<sup>2</sup> = x × x? So it doesn't have to be that complicated:

```
float height = [personHeight.text floatValue];
float floatPersonBMI = [personWeight.text floatValue] * 703 / (height * height);
NSString *stringPersonBMI = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f", floatPersonBMI];
personBMI.text = stringPersonBMI;
```

You can also make the code even simpler than that, and eliminate the use of `[stringPersonBMI release]` (you *do* have that, right?):

```
float height = [personHeight.text floatValue];
float bmi = [personWeight.text floatValue] * 703 / (height * height);
personBMI.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", bmi];
```

Answer (score 2):

C, and thus Objective-C, does not have a raise to the power operator.

In this case, the easiest way is to get the height into a variable and multiply by itself.

e.g.

```
float height = [personHeight.text floatValue];   
float floatPersonBMI = [personWeight.text floatValue] * 703 / (height * height);
```

In general you would use the `pow` function.

```
float floatPersonBMI = [personWeight.text floatValue] * 703 / pow(height, 2.0);
```

Comment: why would you discourage using the pow(x,y)-function?

Comment: Because in this case all he needs is one multiplication and pow is a more general function

Comment: Good point. In my opinion, using pow improves readability (in this case only by a little bit), but that is just personal preference ^_^

Comment: +1 in addition, the `^` character is an [exclusive or](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xor), not an exponentiation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the c function `pow(x,y)` to get x^y, so in your case it would be `(weight*703)/pow(height,2)`

Comment: I've declared methods of personHeight, personWeight, and personBMI so just typing height * height obviously doesn't work. As for using the pow function that does not read as well. Maybe because I have used the result to be in a text field therefore I have to specify personHeight.text. So writing pow(height,2) doesn't work either. Xcode only reads my methods when I use "[]." Still having trouble. Are there any other solutions?